# How is this loop printing a series of integers entered as input?

Tags: c++, c++11, while-loop

Let's take an input : 10 20 30 40 50
**I want the output to print exactly as the input** but the following code prints only 10 as output.

```
#include<iostream>
int main() {

    std::cout << " Please enter sequence of numbers separated by space"
              << " then press enter : ";

    int numbers;
    std::cin>>numbers;
    std::cout << numbers <<' ';
}
```

The reason I think is that the input operator '>>' takes 10 as input and leaves space in the input stream. For the next input, `cin` finds whitespace and concludes that the input has ended. Hence, 10 as output.

Now If I input using a while loop the code prints exactly what I want it to.

```
 int numbers;
 while(std::cin >> numbers)

 std::cout << numbers <<' ';
```

**OUTPUT : `10 20 30 40 50`**

Why does the input work fine using a `while` loop? Please explain what exactly is happening.

Comment: Please explain in your own words how the second snippet work. There seems to be a fundamental misunderstanding of what a `while` loop is.

Comment: `Why the input works fine using a while loop?` because `std::cin` reads a single input and doesn't loop again. And even if it loops then how can it know to call `std::cout` in each loop to print all the inputs?

Comment: "*Why the input works fine using a while loop?*" - Your 1st code reads only 1 input value and then prints out only that value. The rest of the input is not read at all. Your 2nd code reads input values in a loop and prints out each value that is read. What is not to understand about that? Do you understand what a loop even is?

Comment: you really need to read a good book: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/995714). And it's a must to read the documentation of each function you call before using: [std::cout](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) and [std::cin](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin)

Comment: @phuclv "*because `std::cin` reads a single input*" - more accurately, it is `operator>>` that is reading a single input value from `std::cin`.

Comment: @Bob__ I don't know how the second snippet works that's why I asked here. So what a while loop does is it checks  a condition and returns a boolean value . If the condition is true the loop executes and when the condition is false the loop terminates.

Comment: @phuclv Yes I'm using C++ Primer (5th edition). To give more context I encountered this problem yesterday and I was going through the book today (chapter 3 vector operations) where the code snippet uses a while statement to input grades. So thats why I used a while loop .

Comment: Read the documentation of your C++ compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) ...) and of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)). See also [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp). Take inspiration from existing open source C++ software (like [FLTK](http://fltk.org/), [fish](https://fishshell.com/), [ninja](http://ninja-build.org/), [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/)...). If allowed, use the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/)

Answer (score 2):

You're pretty much correct about what's happening in the first example. You enter `10 20 30 40` into `stdin`, but it only takes the first number, 10, as input and stores it into `numbers`. The rest is left stuck in `stdin` and the program exits.

With proper indentation, I believe your code in the second example will be far clearer.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    while (std::cin >> n)
        std::cout << n << ' ';
}
```

Basically, this program works in a pretty weird way. In the first run of the while loop, let's say you input `1 2 3`. Visualizing it, `stdin` would look like this:

```
1 2 3
```

Now, it has to take a number from this. So it takes `1` and then finds a space, so it stops. Now that `1` is in `n`, it prints `1` followed by a space. After the first run of the loop, `stdin` looks like this:

```
2 3
```

In the second run of the loop, it doesn't actually prompt you for more input because `stdin` is not empty. So it'll just take input from what's already there. It sees `2` at the beginning, takes that and stops at the next space, and puts it into `n`. `n` is then printed, followed by a space. `stdin` now looks like this:

```
3
```

Same thing happens with `3`. It takes 3 and puts it into `n` which is printed, and this time `stdin` has been cleared. After this, `std::cin` takes no more input and returns false in the last check of the loop as it has hit `eof`. So to hopefully make things a bit clearer, after unrolling the loop, your program looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    std::cin >> n;         // Here you input "1 2 3", 1 is taken leaving "2 3" in stdin
    std::cout << n << ' '; // "1 " printed
    std::cin >> n;         // 2 is taken from stdin, leaving "3"
    std::cout << n << ' '; // "2 " printed
    std::cin >> n;         // 3 is taken from stdin, nothing left
    std::cout << n << ' '; // "3 " printed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you input **10 20 30 40 50** . It only gets 10 because it ignore all the values after space.
If you get all the values try ***Array*** and used these values in further calculations and print these values using *for and while loops*.

Answer (score 0):

you can loop every digit you want to type with this function:

```
std::string spaceAfterDigit(int len)
{
    std::string digits[256];
    std::string result;
    std::cout << "Type digits but after every digit press enter: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> digits[i];
        std::cout << " ";
        result += digits[i] + " ";
    }

    return result;
}
```

And if you want to convert string to int just use stringstream:

```
stringstream ss;  
ss << result;  
ss >> resultInt;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following I'll show what output [C++ Insights](https://cppinsights.io/about.html) produces from the source code of the second posted snippet (see e.g. [here](https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=I2luY2x1ZGU8aW9zdHJlYW0+CgppbnQgbWFpbigpCnsKCXN0ZDo6Y291dCA8PCAiIFBsZWFzZSBlbnRlciBzZXF1ZW5jZSBvZiBudW1iZXJzIHNlcGFyYXRlZCBieSBzcGFjZSIKICAgIAkJICA8PCAiIHRoZW4gcHJlc3MgZW50ZXIgOiAiOwoKICBpbnQgbnVtYmVyczsKICB3aGlsZShzdGQ6OmNpbj4+bnVtYmVycykKICAgIHN0ZDo6Y291dCA8PCBudW1iZXJzIDw8JyAnOwp9Cg==&insightsOptions=cpp17&std=cpp17&rev=1.0), indentation mine):

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
  std::operator<<(
    std::operator<<(
      std::cout, 
      " Please enter sequence of numbers separated by space"
    ), 
    " then press enter : "
  );

  int numbers;
  while ( static_cast<bool>(
            static_cast<const std::basic_ios<char>&>(
              std::cin.operator>>(numbers)
            ).operator bool()
          ) )
  {
    std::operator<<(std::cout.operator<<(numbers), ' ');
  }
  
}
```

There seems to be a lot of things going on, so let's get the gist of it.

- Despite the unfortunate indentation choices, OP's snippet is equivalent to:

  ```
  int numbers;
  while ( std::cin >> numbers )
  {
      std::cout << numbers <<' '; 
  }
  ```

  This is a simple `while` loop, where the condition, evaluated at each iteration is `std::cin >> number` (more on this, later) and the body, repeated as long as the condition  evaluates `true`, is `std::cout << numbers << ' ';`. So, this is a loop that repeatedly extracts a (single) number from the input stream and puts it into the output stream (along with a space character).
- Now let's take a closer look to that condition.

  `std::cin >> number` is actually a call to the member function [`operator>>(int &)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) of `std::cin`, which

  > Extracts an integer value potentially skipping preceding whitespace. The value is stored to a given reference value. [...]
  > Return value: `*this`.

  So it not only extracts the value from the input stream, but it also returns a reference to `std::cin`. This is useful, because we can use the return value to concatenate operations on this object.
- Another important member function of `std::cin` is [`operator bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool), which

  > Checks whether the stream has no errors. [...]
  > Returns `true` if the stream has no errors and is ready for I/O operations. Specifically, returns `!fail()`.
  > This operator makes it possible to use streams and functions that return references to streams as loop conditions, resulting in the idiomatic C++ input loops such as `while(stream >> value) {...}` or `while(getline(stream, string)){...}`. Such loops execute the loop's body only if the input operation succeeded.